# Inner planes in cube visible at some angles

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Im trying to make simple Tetris game using OpenGL / freeglut.

Camera is placed near center of the board and is looking at falling shape.

When camera is looking up the front plane is not visible - I see the shape from the inside, top and back planes are correct:

[image: Looking up]

However, when shape moves below me, the effect is inverted:

[image: Looking down]

Code responsible for drawing single cube:

```
glLoadIdentity();
glColor4d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
//some texture stuff, however the same happend when using single color
glTranslated(XOffset + CenterX * BrickSize, YOffset + CenterY * BrickSize, ZOffset);
glutSolidCube(BrickSize);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your depth test is off.

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```